# Gibt es Bedeutungsunterschiede zwischen belebt, lebendig und lebhaft?

Tags: difference

Ich würde gern die Unterschiede wissen, da ich finde, dass die drei Wörter schwer zu unterscheiden sind. In einem Buch geht es bei einer Frage um leicht verwechselbare Wörter.

Belebt - lebendig - lebhaft

- Die Schüler waren besonders lebhaft.
- Der Marktplatz ist immer sehr belebt.
- Wir brauchen eine lebendige Demokratie.

Im Duden ist der Ausdruck lebendige Demokratie zu finden. Doch nachdem ich im Internet weiter gesucht hatte, bekam ich Bescheid, dass auch lebhafte Demokratie richtig ist, wobei lebhaft deutlich und klar bedeutet. Außerdem bin ich mir nicht im Klaren, ob es Unterschiede gibt zwischen den drei Wörtern, wenn jemand als *voller Temperament* beschrieben wird.

Answer (score 5):

#### 1) belebt

"Belebt" ist ein Attribut für eine Umgebung. Es bedeutet "mit Leben gefüllt". Das Gegenteil ist "unbelebt". Das Wort beschreibt, wie viel Leben es in einer bestimmten Umgebung gibt. Ein Mensch kann *lebendig* und *lebhaft* sein, aber nicht *belebt*.

> Der Planet Merkur ist unbelebt.
> Der Marktplatz ist an Samstagen belebt, an anderen Tagen sieht man dort fast keine Menschen.
> Die Straße, in der wir wohnen, ist sehr belebt. Man kann nicht mit offenem Fenster schlafen.

#### 2) lebendig

Das ist ein Attribut für etwas, das tot sein kann oder leben kann. Wenn es lebt, ist es lebendig. "Lebendig" ist das Gegenteil von "tot".

> Gesucht: Billy the Kid, Belohnung $500, tot oder lebendig!
> Als Frankenstein den Strom durch den toten Körper fließen ließ, wurde das Monster plötzlich lebendig.
> In einer lebendigen Demokratie fühlen sich die Menschen mitverantwortlich für das Zusammenleben.

"Lebendig" hat noch eine zweite Bedeutung: Je mehr man merkt, dass etwas lebt, desto lebendiger ist es. Zum Beispiel ist ein Kind "besonders lebendig", wenn es sich viel bewegt, viel redet, laut ist.

> Kevin war schon immer ein sehr lebendiges Kind.
> Sarah fühlte sich an diesem Tag so lebendig wie schon lange nicht mehr. "Ich könnte heute Bäume ausreißen!", dachte sie.

#### 3) lebhaft

Dies ist ebenfalls ein Attribut für etwas, das viel Leben zeigt. Die Bedeutung ist etwa die gleiche wie die zweite Bedeutung von "lebendig". Ein mögliches Gegenteil ist hier eher "ruhig" oder "still" (= wenig Leben zeigend).

"Lebhaft" wird sehr häufig im Zusammenhang mit Diskussion, Streit, Meinungsaustausch, Gesprächen etc. benutzt.
In der Musik ist es eine Tempo-Angabe ("vivace" auf italienisch).

> Kevin ist ein sehr lebhaftes Kind.
> In der Wohngemeinschaft gab es heute eine lebhafte Diskussion über den  Putzplan.
> In einer lebendigen Demokratie gibt es oft lebhaften Streit.

> Ronny behauptete, die Innenstadt von Bautzen sei nach 21 Uhr praktisch unbelebt, aber Peggy widersprach ihm lebhaft und sagte, es gebe eine sehr lebendige (*oder:* lebhafte) Clubszene dort.

Comment: Ich würde "leblos" eher als Gegenteil von "lebendig" betrachten und nicht als Gegenteil von "lebhaft". Als Gegenteil von "lebhaft" käme zum Beispiel "ruhig" oder "still" in Frage.

Comment: @Uwe: danke dir, stimme dir zu.

Comment: Erst danke dir. Noch eine Frage: bedeutet Im letzten Satz es gebe eine sehr lebendige Clubszone dort das Wort lebendig etwa wie belebt? Ist das Wort auch durch belebt zu ersetzen?

Comment: @Uwe In Polizei-Verlautbarungen wird (jedenfalls in der Schweiz) „leblos“ als Synonym für „tot“ verwendet („es wurde eine leblose Person aus dem Fluss geborgen“ — gemeint ist nicht „bewusstlos“). Ich weiss nicht genau warum, vielleicht soll es weniger verstörend wirken.

Comment: @Humose: "belebte Clubszene" klingt nicht völlig falsch, aber eine lebendige oder lebhafte Clubszene wäre für mich aktiver als eine belebte, und eigentlich ist Clubszene keine Umgebung, deshalb passt es aus meiner Sicht nicht so gut.